# Fill variable in exported file

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to export a file with email information and a variable of 'name' that will be replaced when importing it to another javascript file.

```
const emailTemplate = {
    subject: 'test',
    body_html: `
    <html>
    <title>
    hey guys
    </title>
    <body>
    Hey ${name}
    </html>
    `
}

module.exports = {
    emailTemplate 
}
```

However, I am not sure how I can fill the name variable when importing it somewhere else, and haven't been really able to look it up. Any ideas on what I could do in this case? Thanks!

This is how I import it in the other file.

```
const emailTemplate = require('./email/template')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export a function to output the html instead.

```
function getBodyHtml(name) {
    // your desired content
    return `
<html>
<title>
hey guys
</title>
<body>
Hey ${name}
</html>`
}

const emailTemplate = {
    subject: 'test',
    getBodyHtml,
}

module.exports = {
    emailTemplate,
};
```

Then, call the function in another file.

```
// anotherFile.js
const emailTemplate = require('./email/template');

// call the function with the `name` variable in order to get the template
const myTemplate = emailTemplate.getBodyHtml('insert name here');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick, didn't think of that.